# Relative linking (RoR)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have some static error pages under `/public`, in which I have linked a stylesheet called errors.min.css in the following manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="errors.min.css">
```

However, while I'm on a path except the root (`/abc/non-existent-url`), the pages don't render properly as the CSS file is not found (since its under a different path now.) I tried setting the URL to:

```
/public/errors.min.css
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there something I can do (except making the CSS inline, which I don't want to do)?

Comment: Try: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/errors.min.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use static stylsheet linking in Rails. Try the following:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "errors.min.css" %>
```

This assumes that the stylesheet is in the `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory.

Also your static pages would have to end with `.html.erb` for this to work.

---

P.S. Static pages should also be made using a controller. See this [tutorial on static pages](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top).